# Do mobile chrome apps run in chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome-app

To put it bluntly, do [Mobile Chrome Apps](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/) have anything to do with chrome at all? After all, it seems reasonable to expect that as it has *Chrome* in the name. This question stems from the fact that as I was porting my 'chrome based mobile app' (which does not run in the 'Browser'), I got a huge string of weird errors and for the first couple of hours I had no idea what was happening.

**NOTE:** This question is **out of date**, Mobile Chrome apps now works differently as outlined in the edit section of the main answer:

> By default, Chrome Apps for Mobile leverage an embeddable Chromium WebView provided by the Crosswalk project by default, which has both advantages and some tradeoffs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note: I work on the (very small) team at Google building the open source project to bring [Chrome Apps to Mobile](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps))

---

First, I’ll paste the description of **Chrome Apps**, right from the top of [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps):

> “Chrome Apps deliver an experience as capable as a native app, but as safe as a web page. Just like web apps, Chrome Apps are written in HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS. But Chrome Apps look and behave like native apps, and they have native-like capabilities that are much more powerful than those available to web apps.
>
> Chrome Apps have access to Chrome APIs and services not available to traditional web sites. You can build powerful apps that interact with network and hardware devices, media tools, and much more.”

Next, I’ll paste the description of **Chrome Apps for Mobile**, right from the top of our [`README.md`](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/README.md):

> “You can run your Chrome Apps on Android and iOS via a toolchain based on Apache Cordova, an open source mobile development framework for building mobile apps with native capabilities using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
>
> Apache Cordova wraps your application's web code with a native application shell and allows you to distribute your hybrid web app via Google Play and/or the Apple App Store. To use Apache Cordova with an existing Chrome App, you use the `cca` (**c** ordova **c** hrome **a** pp) command-line tool.”

---

*Now to answer your question:* “To put it bluntly, do Mobile Chrome Apps have anything to do with chrome at all? After all, it seems reasonable to expect that as it has Chrome in the name.”

*Blunt Answer:*

**No**, they don’t run on Chrome in the same sense that they do on desktop.  However, using `cca` they can run on Mobile in **ways that are most appropriate for those platforms**, and we do use the Chrome Renderer whenever/however we can.

**EDIT as of July 2014**: We now run apps inside the Crosswalk WebView on every version of Android (currently based on Chrome 36, but that will change with time).  I described this approach at the bottom of this original answer, but some of the details about system webviews -- while still accurate -- no longer really apply to Chrome Apps for Mobile.  You can read more about this on our main github page.

Sorry for the naming confusion.  I do see why it is reasonable to assume what you did.  The “**Chrome**” in “**Chrome Apps for Mobile**” refers specifically to the source application type, not to the target runtime type.  We try to document that best we can -- Do you have a suggestion for a simple yet less confusing title?

*Less-Blunt Answer:*

Chrome Apps for Mobile is an open source project to build a tool to support wrapping existing Chrome Apps into Hybrid Mobile Apps, leveraging Apache Cordova.

That is, `cca` creates a 100% real Android/iOS app, like any other, built using the respective Mobile SDK.  Additionally, for your benefit and convenience, we create an app shell that uses the system WebView component to display and run your application content.  We read your application manifest, we simulate the Chrome App lifecycle, we run your background scripts, open chrome app windows, and implement many of the Chrome Apps device apis.  We’ve bundled all this work up into one toolkit which we call `cca`.  We also contribute a lot of patches to core `cordova` to generally make all hybrid apps on Android/iOS better.

Now, the default system WebView’s are as follows:

- *iOS*: Mobile Safari WebKit based.  Lots of web-platform overlap with Chrome, but not exact and diverging slowly.
- *Android 4.3 or older*: Legacy Android WebView.  Dated and occasionally buggy, but still fairly performant on certain tasks.
- *Android 4.4*: Chrome based WebView.  This initial release brought a slew of modern web apis, and enabled remote web inspector.  However, it also introduced some regressions, is stuck at Chrome 30, and didn't bring all features, such as WebGL and WebRTC.
- *Android Future*: Since the first launch of Chrome based WebView, it was announced that work is ongoing to make the WebView auto-update just like the Chrome Browser does.

So, on Android 4.4 we already use a real Chromium renderer to turn your Chrome App into pixels on screen.  On iOS, the WebView is quite modern and performant and many apps should run fine.  For Android Legacy WebView, its hit and miss.  But there is hope...

Excitingly, a significant portion of our recent work on cordova-android has been on bundling a tip-of-tree chromium based “webview” alongside your app, thanks to the [**Intel Crosswalk project**](http://crosswalk-project.org).  This would mean you ship your app to the Play Store together with your very own modern build of Chromium webview.  Best yet, it will work all the way back to Android 4.0.  Expect announcements on how to try it yourself in the next month or so!

---

Finally, while there are some downsides, it's important to note the benefits of our approach:

- By running as a real Android/iOS hybrid app, you can write your own cordova plugins to run native Android/iOS code to augment your application should you find the need to do so.
- Your app distributes using the app store, with user reviews, auto-updates, and monetization.
- Your app has an icon on the users' home screen, and is in the app switcher, etc.
- Most importantly:  You don't have to wait for the future!  Get started today using `cca`, and run your Chrome Apps on iOS and Android using the webviews currently available, and soon to be improved.

Comment: Yeah, I have already gotten my application up and running using the crosswalk project, and I have to apologize for the tone of my original question & answer, which was a combination of being frustrated about the time I had spend to get the thing up & running and on the other hand just wanting to prevent others from making the same mistake. I already had developed for Cordova in the past and seeing Chrome Web Apps I just made the (stupid) assumption that it would just work as the app I already had developed was in my eyes a chrome app (distributed purely over the web + add to homescreen).

Comment: (It doesn't run whatsoever in the legacy webview... lots of graphic artifacts all over the screen, randomly jittery and even crashes, so yeah, unusable and opening it in the android Browser triggered a message to install chrome) Either way, just out of curiosity, why was it not possible to 'just' create an API in chrome to use it's renderer in other 'apps'? I know this would mean certain apps would require the installation of Chrome, but it seems quite a reasonable trade off.

Answer (score 1):

**NO on android 4.3-**, Mobile chrome apps run in the standard `Browser`, **not** in Chrome. The *chrome* part in the name can be considered either a lie or just referring to the part that it supports a few API's that are supported by real Chrome Apps as well.

**Yes, but NO on android 4.4+**, as the standard `android.webkit.WebView` [has been updated](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) to Chrome 30, but will at least for the moment [NOT get the same updates](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#will_the_new_webview_auto-update_) as Chrome and thus end up in the same situation as now where Chrome will run applications differently from the `android.webkit.WebView` again. Technically the answer is still *yes* to the question: *'Does it run in chrome'*, but for all practical means the answer is a clear no (as we're at version 34-36 already now).

This can be found out by either investigating the User Agent or checking for specific support for certain functions. For the user agent mobile chrome apps will return something along the lines of

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-gb; ZP998 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/**534.30** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

And chrome will return

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; ZP998 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/**537.36** (KHTML, like Gecko) **Chrome**/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36

And the browser

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-gb; ZP998 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/**534.30** (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

The expected behaviour of the mobile Chrome apps should have been that the Chrome browser itself would expose an API which they would have used, but instead they really did nothing more than fork cordova and be done with it. On iOS this would have made sense, as that's how the 'Chrome' browser works there as well, but in both cases it should run the same code as Chrome which at the moment of speaking it does not.

Comment: Well, starting with Android 4.4 the answer is apparently different.

Comment: @Xan: Do feel more than free to share that as an answer, because that's news to me :) I just shared what I had found out on my own, as the project documentations make no mention of this whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the answer, actually. This is closest to a docs source I can find: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview But it mentions "The Chrome Apps platform isn't yet supported on Android." I have no idea what to make of that.

Comment: Most relevant: "Will the new WebView auto-update?" answer: "There are large engineering and logistical challenges. We're not quite there yet, but we're working on it."

Comment: @Xan: Updated the answer with info from your link in that case.

Comment: I've answered in detail, but wanted to address one point RE: "they really did nothing more than fork cordova and be done with it".  First, our team has been a significant contributor to cordova project for 2 years now.  Second, we didn't fork cordova, we wrap it, add some hooks, and bundle some of our plugins.  The difference is that you can use `cordova` commands inside `cca` projects.  We fix issues with the platform upstream in `cordova` almost exclusively, and all upstream `cordova` changes apply directly to `cca` releases.  It really is a lot nicer this way.

Comment: @mmocny: My bad, I misinterpreted it as a fork as I thought the API was switched out. Very glad to hear that's not the case, as I have developed (big) apps for cordova in the past (about a year ago) and as a company we dropped it because the legacy webview was just (too) bad, but I am still a huge fan of cordova.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Apps platform defines a set of APIs and a runtime model to make it easy to use web technology to write apps that have native capabilities. You write an app that runs on that platform, and we (the Chrome team at Google) implement the platform on different host architectures. It's "Chrome" in the sense that the Chrome browser, Chromecast, ChromeOS, and Chromebooks are all under the Chrome brand. Chrome does not necessarily mean Chrome web browser.

Yes, on desktop, the Chrome browser happens to be the same executable that implements the Chrome Apps runtime. But to the greatest extent possible, we try to make that just a detail of implementation. A user can use Firefox or Internet Explorer as their default web browser, and never use the Chrome browser, but still use Chrome Apps.

As David Mulder says, Cordova apps (Mobile Chrome Apps) don't use the Chrome browser as their runtime on either iOS or Android. Each Cordova app is its own executable. But where possible, they'll use the Chrome Webview component, so that the inevitable compatibility nits among different webviews are minimized for a given Chrome App.

Comment: It's a pity though that Google felt required to go through misleading advertising by including the chrome trademark in that case in the chrome apps platform. And I hope that the project will soon switch to the crosswalk cordova implementation to least minimize the differences in that case.

Comment: @DavidMulder Ian from our team is currently the primary dev working on the crosswalk cordova-android effort.  So yeah, we share your hope.

Answer (score 0):

Mulder's answer makes no sense to me, and I have no idea what he means when it refers to the user agent. What Cordova does for Chrome Apps is provide the same Chrome App APIs (not all are implemented yet) on Android and iOS, but the resulting app is a native Android or iOS app, which has nothing whatsoever to do with any browser, just as all other Android or iOS apps do not.

In short, the answer is "no."

(The technology does not allow a Chrome App to run on Andoid or iOS. Rather, given the source code of that app, you can build it for those platforms, resulting in a new binary, native app.)

Comment: The technology does not allow a chrome app to run on android? What about Google Chrome? And as mobile chrome apps was developed by Google they could have made a (private) API for themselves in Google Chrome allowing this or compiled a chrome instance into the application like https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: And for that matter, Cordova is just a wrapper around the native webview controls, so the resulting app is native, but it has **everything** to do with the browser running on your device. (Well, iOS split up a couple of components at one point for 'security' reasons, but those are in line nowadays again)

Comment: Don't understand this part: "...everything to do with the browser running on your device." What you get is a native Android or iOS app that is unconnected and unrelated to any browser, Chrome or otherwise.

Comment: It's not native in the sense of written in android 'java', nor is it native in the sense of being a self sufficient platform dependent executable. Instead it's a thin wrapper around the legacy webview (same as the native android browser) which loads into it plain text html, css and javascript files and parses and compiles them at runtime.