# Which rendering engine does Chrome Apps on Mobile use?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, android-webview, google-chrome-app

Apache Cordova apps use the default `WebView` control in Android.

[Change default webkit on Apache Cordova - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805611/change-default-webkit-on-apache-cordova-android)

So for Android 4.4, the `WebView` is using Chromium 30, and will never be updated (on 4.4).

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview

Does the "Chrome Apps on Mobile" version of Apache Cordova, package a Chrome Runtime with it to use for rendering? (please say yes)

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps

Comment: Maybe its just me but I don't understand your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do mobile chrome apps run in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605751/do-mobile-chrome-apps-run-in-chrome)

Comment: @Xan - yes. i just finished reading it. i'm not sure it's a 1:1 duplicate, but it does contain my answer. not sure if i should delete this one or not. thoughts?

Comment: I'd say delete it, otherwise it would be put on hold and closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**. The "Chrome Apps for Mobile" use the default `WebView` just like the normal Apache Cordova.

[Do mobile chrome apps run in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605751/do-mobile-chrome-apps-run-in-chrome)

> The default system WebView’s are as follows:
>
> - *OS*: Mobile Safari WebKit based. Lots of web-platform overlap with    Chrome, but not exact and diverging slowly.
> - *Android 4.3 or older*:    Legacy Android WebView. Dated and occasionally buggy, but still    fairly performant on certain tasks.
> - *Android 4.4*: Chrome based    WebView. This initial release brought a slew of modern web apis, and    enabled remote web
>     inspector. However, it also introduced some    regressions, is stuck
>     at Chrome 30, and didn't bring all features,    such as WebGL and
>     WebRTC.
> - *Android Future*: Since the first launch of    Chrome based WebView, it was announced that work is ongoing to make    the WebView
>     auto-update just like the Chrome Browser does.

Here's the good news quote from May 13th, 2014 from the same answer quoted above:

> Excitingly, a significant portion of our recent work on
>   cordova-android has been on bundling a tip-of-tree chromium based
>   “webview” alongside your app, thanks to the Intel Crosswalk project (https://crosswalk-project.org/).
>   This would mean you ship your app to the Play Store together with your
>   very own modern build of Chromium webview. Best yet, it will work all
>   the way back to Android 4.0. Expect announcements on how to try it
>   yourself in the next month or so!

Comment: You forgot the important part about ongoing work on Crosswalk